# maxima: shorthanding the list of arguments to a function

Tags: function, arguments, variadic-functions, maxima

Suppose I have a bunch of functions such as
`g(x0,x1,x2,x3,x4) := x0+x1+x2+x3+x4+x5`. I would like to use them in other expressions, but explicitly enumerating all the variables `x0,...,x4` is cumbersome. How to shorthand it? I tried something like `vars : [x0,x1,..,x4]` and then passing it like so `g(vars)`, but of course `vars` is considered as a single argument in this case, and I get an error. What I need to do?

EDIT: I was asking for something tad simpler. In my case, the answer would be
something like "create aliases", `G1 : g1(x0,...,x4)` etc kind of thing.
But the answer below highlights a useful thing to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `apply` as stated in the [manual 36.4](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_36.html#SEC201):

```
(%i1) L : [1, 5, -10.2, 4, 3];
(%o1)                 [1, 5, - 10.2, 4, 3]
(%i2) apply (min, L);
(%o2)                        - 10.2
```